# How can I setup RPC using a file system to sync and transfer data instead of a network?

Tags: filesystems, python, rpc

I have two separate networks, and due to network security policies the only bridge between the two is a SMB network share.

How can I setup an RPC system (targeting Python but casting a wider net here) that uses a file system to communicate RPC messages between hosts?

I realize the security implications here (would be very easy to spoof hosts, inject code etc) but In my case both networks are sandboxed so just looking for the easiest solution.